# Regexmach, result store gui editbox

Tags: autohotkey

I have a text, in this text the data is changed, i would like collect the necessary data and show in a gui text boxes.
The first script is a gui the secound script can collet the data from text.
I would like if only the values are loaded to these edit box.

For Instance:

UserInput1 Tony

UserInput2 Stark

UserInput3 34234u4

ect...

First

```
Gui, Add, Edit, x22 y39 w190 h20 vUserInput1 readonly,  
Gui, Add, Edit, x22 y79 w190 h20 vUserInput2 readonly,
Gui, Add, Edit, x22 y119 w190 h20 vUserInput3 readonly,
Gui, Add, Edit, x22 y159 w190 h20 vUserInput4 readonly,
Gui, Add, Edit, x22 y199 w190 h20 vUserInput5 readonly,
Gui, Add, Edit, x22 y239 w190 h20 vUserInput6 readonly,
Gui, Add, Edit, x22 y279 w190 h20 vUserInput7 readonly,
Gui, Add, Edit, x22 y319 w190 h20 vUserInput8 readonly,
Gui, Add, Edit, x22 y359 w190 h20 vUserInput9 readonly,
; Generated using SmartGUI Creator 4.0
Gui, Show, x127 y87 h508 w242, New GUI Window
Return

GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

Secound

```
str=
(
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| Title | |Mr. |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| First Name * | |TONY |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| Last Name * | |STARK |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| Please select the reference | |Rental Agreement Number |
| number type you can provide * | | |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| Providing Number / ID * | |1111111 |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| Reservierungsnummer | |34234u4 |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| Country of Rental * | |usa |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| Rental Station[<BR>](address) | |Airport |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| Pick-Up Date | |15/04/2019 |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| Return Date | |18/04/2019 |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| E-Mail Address * | |tony.stark@pwaero.utc.com |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| | | |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| | | |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| | | |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| | | |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| | | |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| | | |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| | | |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| | | |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| | | |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| | | |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| | | |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| | | |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| | | |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
| | | |
|-----------------------------------+-+-----------------------------------|
)
Loop, Parse, str, `n, `r
{
    If (RegExMatch(A_LoopField,"^\|------|^\| \||Title|Agreement|type") > 0 )
        continue
    m := StrSplit(A_LoopField, "|")

    gui, add, text, xm,% m[4]
}

return

GuiEscape:
GuiClose:
Esc::
  ExitApp
return
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what you want to do is loading the fields of your read-only Edit controls from the string in the second script.

In order to change the contents of the Edit controls, and assuming you are doing so from the same script that created the GUI, you can use the [`GuiControl`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControl.htm#Text) command, with the subcommand `Text` which allows you to set the text of an already created control, instead of adding new Text controls to the GUI.

The syntax of this command is:

```
GuiControl, Text, ControlID[, Value]
```

Where `ControlID` is the variable associated with the control at hand (`UserInput1`, `UserInput2`, and so on) (or also its class' name and instance number (in your case `Edit1`, `Edit2` and successively), or the control's unique identifier, its [HWND](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControlGet.htm#Hwnd)).

For instance, you could replace your loop by this one:

```
count = 1
Loop, Parse, str, `r`n,
{
    If (RegExMatch(A_LoopField,"^\|------|^\| \||Title|Agreement|type") > 0 )
        continue
    m := StrSplit(A_LoopField, "|")

    GuiControl, Text, UserInput%count%, % m[4]
    count += 1
}
```

Which would do the trick.
Notice I use the count variable to reference to the correct Edit control each time.
You don't have to worry about the Edit control being `ReadOnly` since this setting only disallows the user to modify its content, not your scripts.
I've also changed the delimiter of the loop by `` `r`n `` which is the proper line delimiter for parse loops, but that shouldn't affect your script.

---

However, the previous approach assumes that the variables associated to your GUI's controls (`UserInput1`, `UserInput2`, ...) exist in the second script as well, which does **not** happen if they are **not** both included in the same main script using an [`#include`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Include.htm) directive or pasting them both together by hand into the same file.

If your scripts **need** to be separate processes executing on parallel for some reason (probably not), you could still set the control's text from the second script by using the command [`ControlSetText`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSetText.htm) which's syntax is:

```
ControlSetText[, Control, NewText, WinTitle, WinText, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText]
```

In your case you could specify '`EditN`' in the `Control` parameter for your N-th Edit control, and '`New GUI Window ahk_class AutoHotkeyGUI`' for the `WinTitle` parameter (and leave the other parameters blank), which would match your GUI's window and control (unless multiple AutoHotkeyGUIs exist with the same title or more edit controls exist before the first in your GUI). [[More about the WinTitle parameter](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm)].

Using this command, your loop could be rewritten as:

```
count = 1
Loop, Parse, str, `r`n
{
    If (RegExMatch(A_LoopField,"^\|------|^\| \||Title|Agreement|type") > 0 )
        continue
    m := StrSplit(A_LoopField, "|")

    ControlSetText, Edit%count%, % m[4], New GUI Window ahk_class AutoHotkeyGUI
    count += 1
}
```

Where of course, you could substitute '`New GUI Window`' by whichever title you might end using.

---

On another hand, I strongly recommend you to consider a different strategy to store your GUI's data, rather than using that complex markup syntax and your custom (but working ;) ) RegEx.

There exist many different alternatives to store the data of a script in a separated file, but a very simple one could be using an [Ini File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file), able to store key-value pairs of information, structured in sections, for which AutoHotKey provides the built-in commands [`IniRead`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IniRead.htm), [`IniWrite`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IniWrite.htm) and [`IniDelete`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IniDelete.htm)